# PHP Sql Server Output Parameter gives error

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure with a few input parameters and an output parameter. When I am trying to call it from PHP gives me an error. 
My code is as below :

```
$ID = 0;
$sql = "exec Apprasial_Details_Insert 
        @Employee_Name = '".$_POST["Emp_Name"]."',
        @Position = '".$_POST["Position"]."',
        @Dept_Branch = '".$_POST["Branch"]."',
        @Location = '".$_POST["Location"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_1 = '".$_POST["1Appraiser"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_2 = '".$_POST["2Appraiser"]."',
        @Title_1 = '".$_POST["1AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Title_2 = '".$_POST["2AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Date = '$datetime_formatted',
        @Grand_Total = '".$_POST["GrandTotal"]."',
        @Staff_ID = '".$_POST["Staff_ID"]."'
        @new_identity = $ID";
$procedure_params = array
(
    array(&$ID['new_identity'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT)
);      
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,$procedure_params);
if( $stmt === false ) 
{
    //header("Location: error.php?id=$statement"); 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The error I get :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameter) => 102
>   [code] => 102 [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameterhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248244/sql-server-output-parameter-issue) => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '@new_identity'. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near '@new_identity'. ) )

If I change my code to :

```
$sql = "exec Apprasial_Details_Insert 
        @Employee_Name = '".$_POST["Emp_Name"]."',
        @Position = '".$_POST["Position"]."',
        @Dept_Branch = '".$_POST["Branch"]."',
        @Location = '".$_POST["Location"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_1 = '".$_POST["1Appraiser"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_2 = '".$_POST["2Appraiser"]."',
        @Title_1 = '".$_POST["1AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Title_2 = '".$_POST["2AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Date = '$datetime_formatted',
        @Grand_Total = '".$_POST["GrandTotal"]."',
        @Staff_ID = '".$_POST["Staff_ID"]."'
        @new_identity = ?";
$procedure_params = array
(
    array(&$ID['new_identity'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);      
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,$procedure_params);
if( $stmt === false ) 
{
    //header("Location: error.php?id=$statement"); 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The error I get :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameter) => -7
>   [code] => -7 [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameterhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248244/sql-server-output-parameter-issue) => An invalid PHP type was specified as an output
>   parameter. DateTime objects, NULL values, and streams cannot be
>   specified as output parameters. [message] => An invalid PHP type was
>   specified as an output parameter. DateTime objects, NULL values, and
>   streams cannot be specified as output parameters. ) )

I refered to the posts below :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameter)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444516/php-sql-server-output-parameterhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248244/sql-server-output-parameter-issue)

Where have I gone wrong? Appreciate any suggestion / help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need comma after `@Staff_ID = '".$_POST["Staff_ID"]."'` so:

```
$ID = 0;
$sql = "exec Apprasial_Details_Insert 
        @Employee_Name = '".$_POST["Emp_Name"]."',
        @Position = '".$_POST["Position"]."',
        @Dept_Branch = '".$_POST["Branch"]."',
        @Location = '".$_POST["Location"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_1 = '".$_POST["1Appraiser"]."',
        @Appraiser_Name_2 = '".$_POST["2Appraiser"]."',
        @Title_1 = '".$_POST["1AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Title_2 = '".$_POST["2AppraiserTitle"]."',
        @Date = '$datetime_formatted',
        @Grand_Total = '".$_POST["GrandTotal"]."',
        @Staff_ID = '".$_POST["Staff_ID"]."',
        @new_identity = $ID";
$procedure_params = array
(
    array(&$ID['new_identity'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT)
);      
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,$procedure_params);
if( $stmt === false ) 
{
    //header("Location: error.php?id=$statement"); 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Okay, now I feel stupid! thanks for the answer :) Appreciate it :)